# Hiker's Cabin Mystery | Pt. IX

Tags: cipher

You are starting to feel a strange affinity towards this mysterious hiker as you head over to

> The US Embassy in Bern

<sup><sup>*(Answer to Part VIII*)</sup></sup>

as per his instruction.

---

As you walk inside, you notice a man standing at the desk and your pulse begins to quicken. Could this be him? Your mystery hiker?

"Hello," you say to him. 
 He nods back.

You hand over the note and he glances over at it.

"Ah, I see. Unfortunately, the man you must be awaiting is not here, but he told me to give you this message."

He hands you a slip of paper:

`..- . .- -.-- --.. -.-- - - -.-- ...- . -.- ..-. -- ...- .--- ...- . -.- ..-. -- ...- .--- --- -..- ..- . -... -.-- --.. . -. -- -- -.-. -.- -.-- ...- --.. .. -... . ..- -.-- - - -.-- ... - ...- .. -.- ..-. - -... -.-- .--- .. --.- . -.. -.-. .--- . ...- -.-. --.. . -.- -.-- - ..-. .. -.-- .--- -.-- -.-- ...- --. .. ...- -- ...- .--- .. .--- ... -- ...- .--- - ..-. .. -.-- .--- -.-- -.-- ...- - ..-. .. -.-- .--- -.-- -.-- ...- -.-- - - -.-- - ..-. .. -.-- .--- -.-- -.-- ...- ..-. .. --.. .--- ...- . -.-. .. .--- ... -- ...- .--- .. .--- ... -- ...- .--- .- -- ...- . -- .-.. .. ...- --.. ..-. -- ...- .--- -- --.. - -.-- --.. ..- . .- -.-- --.. ..- . .- -.-- --.. --- -..- ..- . -... -.-- --.. -..- . .. - .. ...- -... -.-- .--- .. --.- . -.. -.-. .. .--- ... -- ...- .--- -- --.. - -.-- --.. ..- . .- -.-- --.. .. .--- ... -- ...- .--- -.- -.-- ...- --.. .. -... . ..- -.-- - - -.-- .- -- ...- . -- .. .--- ... -- ...- .--- - ..-. .. -.-- .--- -.-- -.-- ...- -.-- - - -.-- -. -- -.- ..-. -- ...- . -- ..- --- -..- ..- . -... -.-- --.. - ..-. .. -.-- .--- -.-- -.-- ...- --. .. ...- -- ...- .--- -... -.-- .--- .. --.- . -.. -.-. -.-- - - -.-- --. .. ...- -- ...- .--- --. .. ...- -- ...- .--- .. .--- ... -- ...- .---`

Your irritation hits a new level, but you say in a fairly controlled voice, "Thank you, sir."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The slip of paper

> contains Morse code that translates as follows: UEAYZYTTYVEKFMVJVEKFMVJOXUEBYZENMMCKYVZIBEUYTTYSTVIKFTBYJIQEDCJEVCZEKYTFIYJYYVGIVMVJIJSMVJTFIYJYYVTFIYJYYVYTTYTFIYJYYVFIZJVECIJSMVJIJSMVJAMVEMLIVZFMVJMZTYZUEAYZUEAYZOXUEBYZXEITIVBYJIQEDCIJSMVJMZTYZUEAYZIJSMVJKYVZIBEUYTTYAMVEMIJSMVJTFIYJYYVYTTYNMKFMVEMUOXUEBYZTFIYJYYVGIVMVJBYJIQEDCYTTYGIVMVJGIVMVJIJSMVJ

which

> is a cryptogram (simple substitution cipher) for this list of names: SIMON OTTO RICHARD RICHARD YPSILON IZAAK CORNELIS OTTO UTRECHT LODEWIJK DIRK NICO THEODOOR GERARD EDUARD THEODOOR THEODOOR OTTO THEODOOR HENDRIK EDUARD EDUARD MARIA BERNHARD ANTON SIMON SIMON YPSILON PIETER LODEWIJK EDUARD ANTON SIMON EDUARD CORNELIS OTTO MARIA EDUARD THEODOOR OTTO ZACHARIAS YPSILON THEODOOR GERARD LODEWIJK OTTO GERARD GERARD EDUARD

whose

> first letters spell out SORRYICOULDNTGETTOTHEEMBASSYPLEASECOMETOZYTGLOGGE

so

> you should go to the Zytglogge tower.

Although

> you might decide not to trust him, since he claims he couldn't get to the embassy but apparently was able to get there and hand over the piece of paper...

Comment: Very well done, once again, Gareth!